# How to view DNS cache in OSX?

Tags: dns, osx-elcapitan, oscache

To list the entries of DNS cache in **OSX 10.11.6**, I tried `dscacheutil -statistics` but that didn't work.

```
$ sudo dscacheutil -statistics
Unable to get details from the cache node
```

How can I just print what is there in the DNS cache without flushing it?

Comment: Similar questions about using your computer would be better asked at [su].

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**mDNSResponder** (multicast DNS daemon) SIGINFO signal can dump a snapshot summary of the internal state to `/var/log/system.log`, including the cache details. To do this:

Keep system log opened in one terminal:

```
tail -f /private/var/log/system.log
```

Send a SIGINFO signal to mDNSResponder from another terminal:

```
sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder
```

Then check the logs in first terminal, you would be able to see cache dump:

```
mDNSResponder[98]: ------------ Cache -------------
mDNSResponder[98]: Slt Q     TTL if     U Type rdlen
mDNSResponder[98]:  52      1827 -U-      CNAME   17 www.sublimetext.com. CNAME sublimetext.com.
...
...
mDNSResponder[98]: Cache currently contains 154 entities; 3 referenced by active questions
```

(For more info: `man mDNSResponder`)

Comment: I tried this under Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.2 and it doesn't do anything!

Comment: @OlivierdeBroqueville To check logs of `sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder` in Sierra, open **Console** app, select your device on the left sidebar, then apply search filter  _mdnsresponder_, DNS cache logs can be seen there.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! Btw, do you know if it's possible to edit the contents of the DNS cache?

Comment: On newer macOS versions the logs were moved to a new logging system. You can either see them using the Console app, as @PraseethaKR has mentioned, or you can get them from your shell with following command: `log stream --predicate 'process == "mDNSResponder"' --info`

Comment: on my 10.14 MacOS it shows a bunch of private and not the actual info

Comment: Is it possible that this isn't consistent across all versions of macOS? I get different results per version. Is there a definitive command that lists the cache entries?

Comment: I came across this tool on my journey to seeing cache entries across different OS versions. It worked really well: https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/sierra-console-private/

Comment: I am trying in macOS BigSur. This plan will not work.

Comment: Confirmed. This does not work for BigSur.

Comment: I investigated some under-the-mask stuff and I think that maybe have something that can work. Unfortunately I'm a bit scary to test it on my working PC with a lot of company bloatware and I don't have my private Mac. I'm not posting this as an answer because it is not tested. Most probably it should not break MacOS but I can't guarantee it. Here is all my investigation and proposed steps:
https://pastebin.com/BugQTPP4

Answer (score 21):

As @PrasseethaKR and @kjagiello point out, on High Siera mDNSResponer has moved from `syslog` to `log`. In addition, your DNS lookup messages are now considered private and will show as `<private>` in both Console and `log stream` by default.

To view your DNS lookups on High Sierra open an Terminal and run:

```
sudo log config --mode "private_data:on"
log stream --predicate 'process == "mDNSResponder"' --info
```

To go back to using private just run the following command.

```
sudo log config --mode "private_data:off"
```

Cheers!

Comment: No longer works for BigSur

Comment: `log: Invalid Modes 'private_data:on'`

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I can find (macOS 14.2.1)

```
sudo su
dns-sd -Q domain.com
```

---

Live log of the cache flush (open two terminals)

**terminal 1**

```
sudo su
dns-sd -Q domain.com
```

**terminal 2**

```
sudo su
killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Comment: can also ofc skip super-user login via `sudo dns-sd -q domain.com`